# Referencing arrays within json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've spent a day struggling over this one issue and could definitely use some help here. I know it's a newbie sort of question so thanks for any help!!! I have the following sample data in a file 'bar_chart.json'

```
{ "array1":
[
    {"name": "Locke", "value": 2},
    {"name": "Reyes", "value": 50},
    {"name": "Ford", "value": 12},
    {"name": "Jarrah", "value": 35},
    {"name": "Shephard", "value": 15},
    {"name": "Kwon", "value": 4}
],
    "array2":
    [
    {"name": "Jason", "value": 5},
    {"name": "Reston", "value": 13},
    {"name": "Travis", "value": 12},
    {"name": "Matt", "value": 7},
    {"name": "Glenn", "value": 22},
    {"name": "Kyoo", "value": 28}
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the data in array1 to build a bar chart with and that's where I'm having difficulty. Below is the part of my code where I'm receiving the error.

```
d3.json("bar_chart.json", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) { //error occurs here 'undefined is not a function'

        d.name= d.name
        d.value = +d.value;

    });
...
```

I've also tried 'd.array1.name' in place of 'd.name' to no avail. Furthermore, if the data is simplified to where I only have the 1st array without the title, my code works smoothly.

Comment: I believe array1: and array2: need to be in hard brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is an object, you can't call `forEach` on an object, you can only call that on arrays.

you can try `data.array1.forEach(...)` and `data.array2.forEach(...)`

or, you can loop through the object with `for (var x in data) {...}`

Comment: That did it! You guys rock.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment: done like this-

```
[{ "array1":
    [
        {"name": "Locke", "value": 2},
        {"name": "Reyes", "value": 50},
        {"name": "Ford", "value": 12},
        {"name": "Jarrah", "value": 35},
        {"name": "Shephard", "value": 15},
        {"name": "Kwon", "value": 4}
    ]
 },
 { "array2":
    [
        {"name": "Jason", "value": 5},
        {"name": "Reston", "value": 13},
        {"name": "Travis", "value": 12},
        {"name": "Matt", "value": 7},
        {"name": "Glenn", "value": 22},
        {"name": "Kyoo", "value": 28}
    ]
}];
```

The reason this should work is because you are asking forEach which should refer to an array. An object, like you are writing, would be called individually. Like @vic states, with forEach. One for each array.

The way I set your code up is putting your two objects into an array